# Comparison between abstract objects yields wonky error

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

```
Numbers a,b;
a = new NumbersType(1);
b = new NumbersType(1);
System.out.println(a.equals(b));

public class NumbersType implements Numbers {
    int intType;
    public NumbersType (int q) {
        this.intType = q;
    }
    public boolean equals(Numbers n) {
        return this == n;
    }
}

public interface Numbers {
    public boolean equals(Numbers n);
}
```

This prints false, despite both objects being the same thing. Changing `return this == n` to `return this.intType == n.intType` yields error "cannot find symbol: variable intType, location: variable n of type Numbers".

I'm fairly new to ADT and still making my way around it, so excuse me if this is a simple question. I'm not sure why it doesn't work, however, and why I cannot reference `n.intType` but I can `this.intType`.

Comment: **Always implement `equals` as `equals(Object)`**. Don't give it another argument type. This isn't the immediate problem, but it'll cause other nasty issues.

Comment: @user2357112, `Numbers` is an object.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If you give your method the signature `equals(Number)`, then `Object o1 = someNumber; Object o2 = someOtherNumber; o1.equals(o2);` will call the wrong method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intType` is declared on `NumbersType` but `n` is a `Numbers`. So you can't necessarily compare them.

Now, one thing you could do is create a method on the interface that retrieves some value. I say *'some'* value instead of *'the'* value because the other `Numbers` may be some other implementation. This is an important aspect of interfaces. If you have a `Numbers` you cannot know that it is actually a `NumbersType`. (You can find that out with `instanceof` but this would not be a good way to program an interface implementation. The interface's declaration should specify its interactions entirely.)

But first there's kind of a side issue which is that you're declaring an overload of [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). You might be intending to declare an override which is a different thing. For the purpose of my answer, I am going to show an example of both and name the overload something different.

Now here's the modified interface:

```
public interface Numbers {
    public int getIntType();
    public boolean isIntTypeEqual(Numbers n);
}
```

Now that you can retrieve the int, you can compare them in the implementation class.

```
public class NumbersType
implements Numbers {
    private int intType;

    public NumbersType(int intType) {
        this.intType = intType;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntType() {
        return intType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIntTypeEqual(Number n) {
        return intType == n.getIntType();
    }

    // overriding hashCode because we are overriding equals
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return intType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(!(o instanceof Numbers))
            return false;

        return isIntTypeEqual((Numbers)o);
    }
}
```

You may want to read:

- [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [Overriding and Hiding Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

If you are just learning this stuff, `equals` may not be a method you should be trying to implement. It is contractual and easy to get wrong.

Another complication is declaring equals in terms of interfaces: because equals must be symmetric, the implementations *must* override it identically. Otherwise the contract is broken.

Comment: Thank you, this solved everything. I've got a lot of reading to do.

Comment: No problem. Keep reading, and of course ask questions if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your class is `NumbersType` not `Numbers`, so you should type cast a and b in your equals method. This is why you cannot do `n.intType`
2. After you type cast, your equals method should compare `intTypes` of the objects, not direct references. This is why it will not work.

Your naming is a little bit confusing and I would suggest studying Polymorphism in general.

Comment: Initializing `a` and `b` instead as `NumbersType` doesn't solve the issue. I still get the same error.

Comment: @riista are you actually comparing intTypes? And also user2357112 above is right, this is not how you override equals method in Object class.